# Killing Python with a keybinding in VS code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm experimenting with some Python code that generates sound. I'm using VS code. I've set up a keyboard shortcut for the "Python: Run Python File" action, which starts the sound playing in a terminal window.

In order to stop the sound, I have to first click in the terminal panel and then I can do CMD-. (Mac equivalent of ctrl-C.) This takes a couple of seconds though, and if my code is unexpectedly producing a very loud sound I'd like to be able to stop it as quickly as possible.

So my question is, is there a way I can set up a keybinding to immediately stop the running Python process, without first needing to click in the terminal panel where it's running?

There are a number of actions that sounded like they should work, such as "Terminal: Kill the Active Terminal in Editor Area" (bound to CMD-w by default). However, this just seems to close the source file without affecting the terminal at all.

Comment: write kill or terminal on search in settings > shortcuts section of menu and you can set a shortcut for kill terminal or preferences > shortcuts :)

Comment: @SimoNSavioR but see the last paragraph of the question. There is a "kill terminal" action, but for some reason it just closes the source file - it doesn't affect the terminal at all!

Comment: @SimoNSavioR I want to kill the currently running Python process (there should only be one), but I don't care if it kills other terminals as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**try this settings i guess third setting works for you :)**

**[image: terminal kill]**

Comment: Thank you. I was sure I had tried all of those, but "kill all terminals" does indeed work.